# How to add MIME headers in encrypt and sign SMIME data using openssl smime command

Tags: openssl, smime

I was trying to encrypt and sign MIME data using openssl smime command.

I have below MIME data -

```
From:"=?ISO-8859-1?B?3M0SEg=?=" <abc@dcc.final>
Subject:=?ISO-8859-1?B?yNA==?=
 =?ISO-8859-1?B?3IDE4?=
 =?ISO-8859-1?B?OjE0?=
To:<abc@gmail.com>
Message-ID:<FFCFac8b3-9160-4dc7-9263-220e87abd@hostn>
MIME-Version:1.0
Content-Type:Multipart/mixed;boundary="FFCF56959ff9-cc2b-48d6-9d9f-d4dad7885c53"
X-Mailer:UBC 4.0

--FFCF56959ff9-cc2b-48d6-9d9f-d4dad7885c53
Content-Type:text/plain;charset= ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition:inline

U2NXIgTmFtZTogY2FjcGl2CkRhdGU6MjAyNC8wmKJJJSAxggGAMIIB
Mi8wNyAxODoxNApQYWdlczoxCkKLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tmKJJJSAxgjj
LS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tZWxjb21lCg==mKKNIFIOE==KKO
--FFCF56959ff9-cc2b-48d6-9d9f-d4dad7885c53JNVFJNVFIORF
Content-Type:application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition:attachment;
 filename="=?ISO-8859-1?B?DMjQw?=
 =?ISO-8859-1?B?MjAjQw?=
 =?ISO-8859-1?B?MgxNDQ0?=
 =?ISO-8859-1?B?Lng==?="

JVBERi0xLjcKNCAwIG9Y2VzCjw8Ci9YT2JqZWN01MDZ+dq6i4UVJr9
Cjw8IC9QQUdFMDAwMSA3IDAgUiACj4+CmVuZG9i1MDZ+dq6i4JJKJN
IDAgb2JqCjw8Ci9S4wIDAuMCAwLjAgNzI1LjggR+Gt9T7RP4OWhjK0
    .
    .
```

Now I am encrypting this file using command -
openssl smime -encrypt -aes256 -in input.txt -out encrypted.txt cert.pem

But the output encrypted data is as below without any headers (to , from , subject , Message-Id, Date and X-Mailer )

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data; name="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

MIKYLAYJJJZIhUDKNIFNVTBgoJp0HX8irn9V0J3GZjXrn/gunr/DbW
kiaIk/IsZAEZFgVsb2NhbDEYMB1MDZ+dq6i4UVJr9zAw9+fYbJHIMK 
      .
      .
```

and same encrypted data when signed using below command ,no headers are present in that too.

openssl smime -sign -in encrypted.txt -signer cert.pem -inkey key.pem -out out.txt

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/x-pkcs7-signature"; micalg="sha-256"; boundary="----A410BFE85732BF0EEJIHI7EE27400531"

This is an S/MIME signed message

------A410BFE85732BF0EEJIHI7EE27400531
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data; name="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

MIKYvAYJKoZIhvcNAQcDoIKYrTCCmKJJJSAxggGAMIIBfAIBADBkME0xFTATBgoJ
kiaJk/IsZAEZFgVsb2NhbDEYMBYGCgHHEomT8ixkARkWCG9jc3AyMDEyMRowGAYD
VQQDExFPQ1NQLVNTREstMjAxMi1DQQHHTwAAAOhWe3ZfbKVL5gAAAAAA6DANBgkq
          .
          .
```

How to add the headers(to , from , subject , Message-Id, Date and X-Mailer ) in encrypt or signed data? Need to change MIME data or command line flag to add.
I could find "-to", "-from" and "-subject" flags but not for other headers.

Comment: You can create the message source by first writing the To, From, Reply-To, Subject, and Date headers, followed by a blank line, then followed by the output of your openssl command.  Then, send that message source through SMTP, and the recipient's mail client should know what to do with it.

Comment: Check if the [explanations here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49033645/4850949) answer your question.

Comment: @not2savvy thank you, I checked the link shared , indeed it helped little bit but as mentioned in my MIME message already all the headers are present instarting. what does this means "The correct way is to extract these headers from the original message, then add them before the original message body before encrypting".

Comment: @mti2935 thank you, you mean to add the headers (whatever is required) manually in a file and then add the command output (sign or encrypt) and then pass it to client . am I correct ?

Comment: @scodeninja Yes, it can be done manually, the way you described.  It can also be automated, by using shell commands or a scripting language (e.g. python) to add the headers, then send the message through a local MTA (e.g. /usr/sbin/sendmail) or a remote SMTP server (e.g. smtp.gmail.com).

Comment: @mti2935 ok, is there is no way to do it by openssl smime command. like -to -from and -subject flag is there. likewise for message id, date and x-mailer is not there?

Comment: @scodeninja Looking at the [man page for openssl smime](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/smime.html) it looks like to -to, -from, -subject flags do indeed add these headers 'outside' the signed portion of the message.  So, these may do what you want.  But, there does not seem to be similar flags for other important headers (like date, message id, etc.) so these headers would need to be added to the message separately.  In the past, I've used a python script to add all the headers (without relying on the openssl smime flags), and send the message through a remote outgoing SMTP server.